# JsonSerializer.Deserialize exception: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to read this json string **players.Metadata**:

```
{"drunk":0,"isbleeding":false,"stress":5,"licences":{"drive_boat":false,"hunting":false,"business":false,"driver_bike":false,"dmv":true,"weapon":false,"drive_truck":false,"drive_fly":false,"driver":true},"tracker":false,"craftingrep":0,"commandbinds":[],"phonedata":{"SerialNumber":86505294,"InstalledApps":[]},"bloodtype":"B+","status":[],"walletid":"QB-40404499","poop":0,"isdead":false,"fingerprint":"NQ795L08aVN5152","jobrep":{"taxi":0,"trucker":0,"hotdog":0,"tow":0},"callsign":"NO CALLSIGN","armor":100,"hunger":83.19999999999709,"criminalrecord":{"hasRecord":false},"inside":{"apartment":[]},"inlaststand":false,"ishandcuffed":false,"fitbit":[],"attachmentcraftingrep":0,"inpdjail":0,"beard":0.0,"injail":0,"currentapartment":"apartment56922","jailitems":[],"phone":[],"clean":98.0,"dealerrep":0,"drug":0,"thirst":84.79999999999927}
```

This is how it looks with **json visualizer**:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

**Metadata.cs** (only including field related to error as other fields are working)

```
public class Metadata
{
    /* All other fields are working or didn't step into them */
    public string fitbit { get; set; }        
}
```

**Main.cs**

```
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
metadata = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Metadata>(players.Metadata);
```

**Error msg:** System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.fitbit | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 650.'

How can I convert it correctly?

Comment: `[ ]` indicates that the data type is an array/list. Your `fitbit` property is declared as a `string`. Changing the data type to array should resolve the issue (as long as everything else is ok)

Comment: Please try changing the type from `string` to an array type, such as `object[]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is invalid, one of the property fitbit has string value, another is shown as an empty array. Change your Metadata class

```
public class Metadata
{
   public object fitbit { get; set; }       
}
```

or fix your json

```
"fitbit" : "",
```

Comment: Just saw that when the json string is empty it comes as "[]" but when it has data it's not an array. I will just set a jsonstring.replace("[]", "\"\"");

Comment: @AdrianHernandoSolanas See my answer for your previous question. It is the same. What data it is when it is not empty?

Comment: Watching with text visualizer: "fitbit":{"food":30,"thirst":30}

Comment: @AdrianHernandoSolanas Is it always the same? I mean when it is not empty?

Comment: the integers (food, thirst) can change but nothing else, the schema is always the same but the integer values can be different. So I can get nill or I can get those 2 values

Answer (score 0):

Because fitbit is an empty array. It is not a string.

Comment: Acknowledging that @Serge's answer came in after yours, it nevertheless provides a good example of how to answer questions like this. Your answer is correct, but Serge's answer is more useful by adding additional context and options for resolving the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I will pay attention to my answers.